# Caching big files for local network, with authentication on internet

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, proxy, squid

I'm trying to do something which I'm sure it's been done before, so I would like some help finding the best tools for the job.

I have a data download server on the web, right now a user has to login into the server and request a file, with Apache httpd serves directly over the net.

Since the files are quite big, I want to setup a machine currently functioning as a router to our LAN, so that the downloads happen from it to any user connected to our LAN, but the authentication of user still has to happen on the web server. Furthermore, I don't want my users to deal with this change, they should login and request the file, and the local router should take over in case they are in the LAN, otherwise they should receive the file from the internet.

I guess I have to setup a local apache server in the router, so that it can serve the files, but I'm not sure how to intercept the request for a file, request the authentication from the server and still serve the file from the local router. I'm reading the documentation of Squid, since at first it appear to be able to do something of the like, but I would appreciate some direction from more experience people.

Is squid the right tool for this problem? Are there better alternatives?

Other solution I've thought about is maintaining a local copy of the authentication database, so that when a user request a file, I only need to intercept that request and run the authentication locally and serve the file, the problem is that file permissions are quite volatile, and I don't know of a good way to keep both databases in sync automatically. Is there some tool to help in this regard?

Comment: Take a look at [HTTP-replicator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/http-replicator/). It is caching proxy for files. When it receives request for file it will first check for its local copy in cache and only if there is no cached file it will get it from remote resource. Not sure how it handles authorization. Also, there is no support for HTTPS. Written in Python. Probably not best option for you.